# Merging data frames in R4.0.0 60x slower than R3.6.3?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Merging 2 data frames in R4.0.0 is much slower than in R.3.6.3.

**Reproducible example**:

```
library(reshape2)

n <- matrix(1:6000000, nrow=15000, ncol=400)
colnames(n) <- 1:ncol(n)

meta <- data.frame("col1" = ncol(n):1, row.names = colnames(n))
start_time <- Sys.time()
test = sapply(1:nrow(n), 
               function(i) {
                 print(i)
                 nn = reshape2::melt(n[i,])
                 tmp = merge(nn, meta, by="row.names");
               }
)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time-start_time
```

This code takes 23 seconds in R3.6.3 and 23 minutes in R4.0.0 (on my machine) - making the merge **60 times slower**!
The 'melt' function is not the time consuming step.

This issue is also not related to sapply. You can reproduce the extreme speed difference using a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(n)){
  print(i)
  nn = reshape2::melt(n[i,])
  tmp = merge(nn, meta, by="row.names");
}
```

I'd be happy to hear your feedback! Am I missing something?

(I have previously asked this question in another context and have deleted the old question since it wasn't reproducible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **actually a bug** in R4.0.0.

I have submitted it to R-core (https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17794) and update here once it is fixed.

**Update**
The bug has been **fixed** by the R-team (thanks to Martin Maechler!), is already rolled out in R-devel, and the fix will be included in the next release version of R.